# Suddenly missing icons in the Office 365 App Launcher

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-web-apps

Three weeks ago suddenly a lot of our users did not see all icons in the Office 365 App Launcher. The users could no longer see the icons for Office Online, Sites or OneDrive for Business.

I do not know what has happened since this has been working properly earlier and there has not been any changes made here that should affect this.

The manual solution is to disable the licenses for “Office Online” and “SharePoint Online” and then re-enable them again after 10 minutes.
However we are talking about +1000 users and we need to identify why this has happened and we also need to get the icons back for all affected users.

Does anyone know what has caused this problem and how we can “recover” the icons for all affected users?

Best Regards, Magnus

Comment: You should probably raise a support request through the Office 365 portal.

Comment: You can try just for test to remove and re-added the user sharepoint license.
But like Eric said it's good option to open a service request.

Comment: @bcastilho , as i wrote in my question, i have already tried that but i am not interested in manually reassign +1000 licenses. I have created a Service Request now and waiting for the answer. If i get a good/satisfying solution/explanation i will publish it here as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I solved it by reassignig the licenses for the users.
:-)

Answer (score 2):

This is now solved. In my case the issue was be related to the synchronization process of the users and that the users has not been completely synced with the "license information". After MS made a user synchronization of this everything worked.

Comment: Can you elaborate bit about the fix? Were you using Active directory import?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem today for one of our employees.  She had logged in with her company address as a personal account at some point.  I had her log out and then to log back in, I had her log in as a different account but enter the same email address.  Then the window popped up that said "it looks like there is more than one account with this address", with options to select work or personal accounts.  I had her select work, and all of her apps were back where they belong.  I hope this works for someone else.